# A better way? Have date in query always use a date in the current year without maintenance

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SELECT Date_Received, DateAdd(Year, DateDiff(year, Cast('3/01/2010 12:00:00AM' as DateTime) , 
    GetDate())-1, Cast('3/01/2010 12:00:00AM' as DateTime)) as minimum_date
FROM [Volunteers].[dbo].[Applications]
WHERE Date_received >= DateAdd(Year, DateDiff(year, Cast('3/01/2010 12:00:00AM' as DateTime),
GetDate())-1, Cast('3/01/2010 12:00:00AM' as DateTime))
```

In several subqueries where I need to check that a date is within an acceptable range. I need to avoid using a simple constant as I really don't want to update it or a config file each new school year.

My current solution is to enter the date into the query and use some complicated `DATEADD` tricks to get the current year(or previous year) into the date I am using in the comparison. The exact code is above. Is there a cleaner way for me to do this?

Thanks

Edit

The business requirement is to find applications submitted between 3/01 and 7/31.

We are running background checks and it costs us money for each check we do. Identifying applications submitted during this time period helps us determine if we should do a full, partial or no background check. I will also need to check if dates concerning the previous year.

We will be doing this every year and we need to know if they were in the current year. Maintaining the queries each year to update the dates is not something I want to do.

So I am looking for a good technique to keep the year parts of the dates relevant without having to update the query or a config file.

Comment: what significance does the year 2080 have? What are your boundary dates for the acceptable range? Can you state what the business rule is?

Comment: it has the significance of a typo. it should read 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to query by month and year a lot, you should also consider making those properties into persisted, computed fields:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Applications
    ADD DateReceivedMonth AS MONTH(Date_Received) PERSISTED

ALTER TABLE dbo.Applications
    ADD DateReceivedYear AS YEAR(Date_Received) PERSISTED
```

SQL Server will now extract the MONTH and YEAR part of your `Date_Received` and place them into two new columns. Those are persisted, e.g. stored along side with your table data. SQL Server will make sure to keep them up to date automatically, e.g. if you change `Date_Received`, those two new columns will be recomputed (but not on every SELECT).

Now, your queries might be a lot easier:

```
SELECT (list of fields)
FROM dbo.Applications
WHERE DateReceivedYear = 2010 AND DateReceivedMonth BETWEEN 3 AND 7
```

Since these are persisted fields, you can even put an index on them to speed up queries against them!

Comment: That is great. That will really simplify my queries.

Comment: One issue with this solution. It can cause an error with SQL inserts to the table unless you SET ARITHABORT ON. this can be done at the database level.

Answer (score 3):

Old TSQL trick: cast the date to a string in a format that starts with the four-digit year, using substring to take the first four characters of that, cast it back to a date.

Actually, the reason that it's an *old* TSQL trick is that, if I recall correctly, there wasn't a year() function back then. Given that there's one now, using year( getdate() ) , as others' have answered, is probably the better answer.

Comment: 20 or 120 should do the trick; http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeFormats.aspx

Comment: Yeah, it's been a few years since I've touched TSQL, but the 120 format rings a bell.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())
```

will give you the current year.

Comment: and MONTH(yourdate) will give you the month for that date - use those and you should be fine!

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you cannot simply use the [Year](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) function?

```
Select Date_Received
        , Year(GetDate()) 
                - Year('3/01/2010 12:00:00AM') - 1 
                + Year('3/01/2010 12:00:00AM')
From [Volunteers].[dbo].[Applications]
Where Date_received >= ( Year(GetDate()) 
                        - Year('3/01/2010 12:00:00AM') - 1 
                        + Year('3/01/2080 12:00:00AM') )
```

Another way would be to use a common-table expression

```
With Years As
    (
    Select Year(GetDate()) As CurrentYear
        , Year('3/01/2010 12:00:00AM') As ParamYear
        , Year('3/01/2080 12:00:00AM') As BoundaryYear
    )
Select Date_Received
    , CurrentYear - Years.ParamYear - 1 + Years.ParamYear
From [Volunteers].[dbo].[Applications]
    Cross Join Years
Where Date_received >= ( Years.CurrentYear 
                            - Years.ParamYear - 1 + Years.BoundaryYear )
```

Answer (score 1):

TSQL Function returns four digit year dependent on year. This behaves much like the standard SQL YEAR functions ***[Thomas - nod]*** which 'CAN' be tweaked using sp_configure on the advanced options, however, the code below is provided as a framework for CUSTOM requirements and can be modified as required. e.g. return as int, use with standard DATETIME functions in SQL to achieve what is needed. e.g. When working with "dirty" data I had to migrate, I used it with the PATINDEX() function to strip non-numeric values etc.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Andrew McLintock
-- Create date: 13 July 2016
-- Description: Return 4-digit YEAR
-- =============================================
/*
SELECT Staging.fn_4year('06')
SELECT Staging.fn_4year('56')
SELECT Staging.fn_4year('99')
SELECT Staging.fn_4year('1906')
SELECT Staging.fn_4year('2025')

*/
CREATE FUNCTION Staging.fn_4year
(
    @year_in varchar (4)
)
RETURNS varchar(4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @yeartmp int, @Retval varchar(4)
    SET @yeartmp = CAST(REPLACE(@year_in,' ','') AS INT)
    IF LEN(CAST(@yeartmp AS Varchar)) = 4
    BEGIN
        Return cast(@yeartmp as varchar(4))
    END
    IF LEN(@year_in) = 2
    BEGIN

        SET @Retval = CAST(iif(@yeartmp  > 49, @yeartmp + 1900, @yeartmp + 2000) AS varchar(4))
    END


    RETURN @Retval

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider keeping a set of `datetime` variables help readability and maintainability. I'm not sure I've captured all your requirements, especially with reference to 'previous year'. If it's as simple as finding applications submitted between 3/01 and 7/31, then this should work. If you need to determine those that were submitted Aug 1 (last year) through Feb 28 (current year), this solution could be modified to suit.

```
DECLARE @Start smalldatetime, @End smalldatetime, @CurrYear char(4)
SELECT @CurrYear = YEAR(getdate())      

SELECT @Start = CAST( 'mar 1 ' + @CurrYear as smalldatetime),
        @End = CAST( 'jul 31 ' + @CurrYear  as smalldatetime)

 SELECT * 
 FROM Applications
 WHERE Date_Received
 BETWEEN @Start AND @End
```